# I Can't do the Thieves Guild Questline

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm a Khajiit Character in Skyrim, I just made the character and now I've decided to join the Thieves Guild. The first quest I have to do is collect the debt from the three people, but as a Khajiit whenever I initiate a brawl, I end up doing lethal damage (yes with my fists) and everybody around me starts trying to kill me with daggers and I always end up killing the target with my hands rather than just knocking him on the ground. Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE: Whenever I'm attacked the target everyone around me attacks as well.

Comment: Looking around. Saw this thread: http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3235004. What equipment are you wearing?

Comment: ^ What DCShannon said. Make sure you don't have anything on with enchantments that increase damage in unarmed combat. Do you have any followers with you? Make sure you dismiss them before starting a brawl. Are you using any mods?

Comment: If you play on PC, I generally suggest installing the [Unofficial Patch](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=549915017&searchtext=unofficial+patch) (If you don't have legendary edition, there's separate mods for the base game and every DLC, too). These patches contain a *huge* amount of fixes that Bethesda never bothered to do themselves. It *might* solve your issue as well. Make sure to post it as an answer if it does.

Comment: @DCShannon I HAD the Pugilists on, but then I tried using them and I thought they were the problem so I took them off and same problem.

Comment: @pushasha Yeah, I'm using mods though I don't think they are relevant to brawls, I'm using Dragon Diversity, Archery Gameplay Overload, Enhanced First Person View, Moonpath to Elsweyr, Elemental Arrows, FNIS, Apocalypse Spells, and VioLens.

Comment: Supposedly the Ebony Mail will cause this problem, since it has an aura that does poison damage to enemies. Are you wearing the Ebony Mail or something similar? I think you should just list all your equipment, or try a brawl naked and see if that helps.

Comment: @DCShannon No, I'm wearing All Imperial armor and a Novice Mage Hood

Comment: This shouldn't be an issue, but you are running mods, so perhaps. Do you have the perk that adds your gauntlet armor to your unarmed attacks?

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty solution: Change your race:

Open the console (the "`" key next to the "1" key), type

```
showracemenu
```

This will show the initial character creation menu. Change your race from Khajit to something else. Complete the quest without scratching your opponent with your cat's claws. Repeat to change your race back.

A sidenote: I had a minor issue with changing race: I've changed from Khaijit to Dwemer, but after each change to werewolf form and back, game was resetting my race to Khajit, forcing me to again manually change it, but since you are in the end want to stay in the original race this shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score -1):

You could try increasing the difficulty of the game for these quests - This will lower the amount of damage you will deal (and increase the amount of damage you receive). This should let you bring your target to low health without killing him.

Comment: I don't think the problem is that the asker is killing the enemy, it's that their damage isn't registered as non-lethal, so everyone turns on them for attacking the guy unprovoked.